# Aggregate or similar function in SQL Views

Tags: sql, db2

There is a table **CUST_ORDERS**

```
CustID  OrderID InvoiceAmt
1       1       100
1       2       60
2       3       90
3       4       10
3       5       20
```

I want to create a SQL `VIEW` for this which contains aggregate of `InvoiceAmt` for each Customer

```
CustID  InvoiceAmt
1       160
2       90
3       30
```

As can be seen above, For `CustID` `1`, `InvoiceAmt` is `100 + 60` = `160`

How can this be achieved using a `VIEW` ?

If not, can it be achieved using triggers ?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  Can you write the query that does what you want?

Answer (score 1):

create view

```
create view my_view  as 
select  custID, sum(InvoiceAmt) sum_invoice_amt
from CUST_ORDERS
group by custID
```

then select from view

```
select * from my_view
```

or explicitally

```
select custID, sum_invoice_amt 
from my_view
```

Comment: When would this view be updated ? On `SELECT` on `MY_VIEW` or on `INSERT` to `CUST_ORDERS` ?

Comment: And are there any problems associated w.r.t growing size of `CUST_ORDERS` ? Would `SELECT` on view  / `INSERT` on `CUST_ORDERS` become slow ?

Comment: Each time you insert or update  or delete from  .. obviusly you see the effect by the view  ..  the view is  just a piece of sql code stored  in db and used  each time you call the view name (is pratically a subquery  already available)

Comment: For preformance  all the index you apply to cust_orders are directly available for the view  (hope my comment is clear)